# RDD filter with exact word match search

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an rdd object(created from a text file) and I am creating another rdd object by filtering with exact matching word.

```
rdd2 = rdd1.filter(lambda x: word in x)
```

`word` is a string generated in a for loop. So I will be searching for some words in `rdd1` in a loop. For example, if my word value is 'ebook'. So, when I am searching the rdd1, I am getting all the lines matching ebook. But, I am also getting lines with value 'ebooks'.

How to filter an rdd with exact word match? `rdd2` should contain lines with only exact matching word, which is `ebook` not `ebooks`.

I need to create an intermediate rdd for further processes. Please help.

Comment: likely: `rdd2 = rdd1.filter(lambda x: word in x.split())`

Comment: Thanks. x.split() worked for the exact word match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rdd2 = rdd1.filter(lambda x: word in x.split())
```

`x.split()` worked for the exact word match.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.